# Constraining generic parameter of Rust struct to be Deserialize

Tags: generics, rust, serde

I would like to limit a (de)serializable struct to have a generic parameter that is also deserializable. The derive macro `Deserialize` does not require me to add this constraint, which is nice, but I would like the integration code to get compilation errors even if they never try to deserialize the struct defined in the library.

```rust
use failure::Fallible; // 0.1.6
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize}; // 1.0.104
use serde_json::to_string_pretty; // 1.0.44

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct X<T>
where
    // T: Serialize,
{
    a: u8,
    t: T,
}

type Main<'a> = &'a dyn Fn() -> Fallible<()>;

fn main() -> Fallible<()> {
    let x = X { a: 1, t: false };
    println!("{}", to_string_pretty(&x)?);

    let y: X<bool> = serde_json::from_str(r#"{"a":2,"t":true}"#)?;
    println!("{}", y.t);

    let _z: X<Main> = X { a: 3, t: &main };
    // println!("{}", to_string_pretty(&z)?);

    //let w: X<Main> = serde_json::from_str(r#"{"a":4,"t":NONONO}"#)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e3a956e4097fdf87344a5bf905a88418)

- The compilation fails if I uncomment the line with `to_string_pretty(&z)`, which is good.
- Even without that line, the compilation fails on the `let _z = ...` line if I uncomment `where T: Serialize`. This is great, because it helps the library integrators to spot they are using `struct X` with a non-serializable type parameter even before they actually start serializing it.

I have tried to add `where for<'a> T: serde::de::Deserialize<'a>` as a constraint to `struct X<T>`, but that breaks the build even without anything using `X`

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct X<T>
where
    for<'a> T: serde::de::Deserialize<'a>,
{
    a: u8,
    t: T,
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1a6bea41ec5d288ce84a4c0ea95c6a48)

Is there a way to phrase this constraint I am looking for?

Comment: Can you post the exact code that you want to work, and add the error message you are getting? I'm not sure which lines you want to uncomment.

Comment: Okay. Tried to clarify the non-working attempt to the library code.

Comment: That helps, thanks! Unfortunately I'm still as mystified as you are...

Comment: The 1st code proves that you can instantiate X<Main> without Main being Deserialize. No error unless you actually deserialize X<Main>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [`#[serde(bound)]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#bound) to prevent Serde from attempting to automatically determine the bounds on the `Deserialize` and `Serialize` implementations:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[serde(bound = "T: Serialize, for<'de2> T: Deserialize<'de2>")]
struct X<T>
where
    T: Serialize,
    for<'de2> T: Deserialize<'de2>,
{
    t: T,
}

struct NotSerializable;

fn main() {
    X { t: true };

    // X { t: NotSerializable }; // Generates compiler error
}
```

See also:

- [Deriving Serde's Serialize or Deserialize forces generic type to be serialisable although it does not need to be](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50047334/155423)
- [Rust and serde deserializing using generics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54851996/155423)
- [Cannot resolve T: serde::Deserialize<'a> when deriving Deserialize on a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49953960/155423)

Comment: Wow. Thanks. [This github discussion](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/964) with serde author dtolnay also helped to understand why it works like this.